# Custom color for icons in Expanded SearchView in Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview, android-styles

I have made the primary app color as white and afterward, the icons in expanded SearchView are not visible as they are also in white color. For other toolbar icons and overflow icons, I was able to set alternate icons using style.xml

Current style applied to the Activity through manifest file is:

```
<style name="RecyclerAppTheme" parent="BaseTheme" />

    <style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <!-- Spark -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
        <item name="titleTextColor">@color/black</item>
        <!-- <item name="colorControlHighlight">#D3D3D3</item>
-->
        <!--<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item> // change this color to the required cursor color your need.-->

        <!--<item name="colorPrimary">#1999DA</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1999DA</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">#1999DA</item>-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

        <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_item_background</item>
        <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_item_background</item>

        <!-- Spark -->
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/DarkOverFlowButton</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/DarkOverFlowButton</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/actionbar_black</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="editTextColor">@color/black</item>
        <!--  below things for action menu -->

        <!--       <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OptionsMenu</item>-->

        <!-- End of Action menu-->
    </style>
```

Comment: Hi Midhun, currently unsure of what you are trying to ask, could you please clarify your question?

Comment: @chirag90 i have added the activities style as well in the query above. After applying the style, the controls in expanded searchView in the activities toobar are not visible as they all are in white color.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Accent colours, for example.

In your styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#455a64</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#37474f</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#c62828</item>
</style>
```

Will give you a dark primary and red controls. Customise these colours to your colour palette.

Comment: colorAccent is given as black still not working. I have updated the style used for the activity. pls have a look

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible to use multiple theme.

in your style.xml you will need to add a new theme like this :

```
 <style name="ThemeName">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
</style>
```

In your layout.xml, you will have to add this line  `android:theme="@style/ThemeName"`

See : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I tried applying the colorAccent, still not working.. Updated the style used in the qestion above.